# Как уместить картинку в ячейке, в мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, вёрстка

Скажите пожалуйста как мне автоматически уместить картинки (150x180) в ячейках резиновой таблицы(`<table>`)? Пробовал по разному делать, но они ни как не хотят стать адаптированными, из-за них таблица становится уже шире экрана и сайт становится не очень уж и мобильным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row" style="
         margin-right: 0;
         margin-left: 0;
         ">
         <div class="col-xs-4" style="
            width: 100%;
            ">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" style="
               width: 100%;
               ">
               <tr>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
                  <td valign="top"><input type="image" src="images/smile.png" name="имя"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: скиньте код, пожалуйста

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, оформите свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
input[type="image"] {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x180" name="имя">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x180" name="имя">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x180" name="имя">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x180" name="имя">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x180" name="имя">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```